# WordPress: Getting subcategories from parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom taxonomy called `Resources`. Within resources, I have defined a category called "type". This is its structure:

```
Type
   - Blog
   - Case study
   - Webinar
```

So category "type" has three sub categories.

I'm trying to get (and display) the subcategories from the parent. But the `array` is showing up empty?

`Type` has the ID of 32.

**Approach:**

```
$type_id = 32;

$taxonomies = array( 
    'category',
);

$args = array(
    'parent'         => $type_id,
    // 'child_of'      => $type_id, 
); 

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
```

`var_dump($terms);` returns `array(0) { }`

**Edit:**

How I've defined the taxonomy:

```
register_post_type(
            'resources',
            tp_build_post_args(
                'resources', 'Resource', 'Resources',
                array(
                    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
                    'menu_position' => 20,
                    'has_archive'   => true,
                    'public'      => true,
                    'supports' => array('editor', 'title','author','thumbnail', 'revisions'),
                    'taxonomies' => array('resource', 'category')
                )
            )
        );
```

And also tried:

```
$type_id = 32;

$taxonomies = array( 
    'resource',
);

$args = array(
    'parent'         => $type_id,
    // 'child_of'      => $type_id, 
); 

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
```

`var_dump($terms)` now returns `object(WP_Error)#5443 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Invalid taxonomy." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }`

Comment: You may be querying the wrong taxonomy.  You're showing 'category' as the taxonomy, which is the default taxonomy.  You said you created a custom taxonomy.  Try querying that, or just using the term without the taxonomy defined.

Comment: @DubVader - Yeah, I've tried to change it to `resources`, but still no luck. I've updated my question to show the latest approach

Comment: Did you actually register the taxonomy as well, or just the post type?  If the taxonomy itself is not registered it won't be recognized.  If you haven't you'll need to do that.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/